# How is this bash script launching a program?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, execution, exploit

I am looking into how a particular exploit works, and I chose to look at one in the program 'chkrootkit' which allows for any user to run a malicious file as root. The source code for this vulnerable shellscript is as follows

```
slapper (){
   SLAPPER_FILES="${ROOTDIR}tmp/.bugtraq ${ROOTDIR}tmp/.bugtraq.c"
   SLAPPER_FILES="$SLAPPER_FILES ${ROOTDIR}tmp/.unlock ${ROOTDIR}tmp/httpd \
   ${ROOTDIR}tmp/update ${ROOTDIR}tmp/.cinik ${ROOTDIR}tmp/.b"a
   SLAPPER_PORT="0.0:2002 |0.0:4156 |0.0:1978 |0.0:1812 |0.0:2015 "
   OPT=-an
   STATUS=0
   file_port=

   if ${netstat} "${OPT}"|${egrep} "^tcp"|${egrep} "${SLAPPER_PORT}">
/dev/null 2>&1
      then
      STATUS=1
      [ "$SYSTEM" = "Linux" ] && file_port=`netstat -p ${OPT} | \
         $egrep ^tcp|$egrep "${SLAPPER_PORT}" | ${awk} '{ print  $7 }' |
tr -d :`
   fi
   for i in ${SLAPPER_FILES}; do
      if [ -f ${i} ]; then
         file_port=$file_port $i
         STATUS=1
      fi
   done
   if [ ${STATUS} -eq 1 ] ;then
      echo "Warning: Possible Slapper Worm installed ($file_port)"
   else
      if [ "${QUIET}" != "t" ]; then echo "not infected"; fi
         return ${NOT_INFECTED}
   fi
}
```

I know that the reason the exploit works is because the line 'file_port=$file_port $i' will execute all files specified in $SLAPPER_FILES as the user chkrootkit is running (usually root), if $file_port is empty, because of missing quotation marks around the
variable assignment."

My question is *why* does the command

```
file_port=$file_port $i
```

result in execution of the file? Assuming that $i refers to the path of the file (/tmp/update)

I can see that file_port might be changed to some long netstat command in the previous if statement, is this something to do with it?

I've been trying to get my head around this all day to no avail, so at this point any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *one-shot* variable assignment feature of any Bourne shell. Any command can be prefixed with zero or more variable assignments:

```
VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2 command arguments ...
```

Runs `command arguments ...` with the respective environment variables set for just this command. A typical use might be

```
EDITOR=vim crontab -e
```

Comment: Right that does make more sense now, do you have any idea what file_port actually is? in your example it's obvious you are setting the editor to use when editing the crontab, but what do you think it is in this case?

Should I just assume file_port is some variable the worm would look for if  it was present?

Comment: @ASliceOfBread Wild assed guess: file_port references a TCP or UDP port, receiving or sending a file.

Comment: yeah I expect it is something along those lines, thanks for the help!

Comment: out of interest, why does adding quote marks around $file_port $i fix the problem? ( as in you can no longer run any arbitrary program called update)

Comment: The important part isn't that the worm looks for a value named `file_port`, it is that the shell treats (the expansion of) `$i` as a word in command position preceded by an assignment, as opposed to part of the value of the assignment.

Comment: So the aim of the statement is to set `file_port` to `"$file_port $i"`, and not run the program at all? would that not make this also a logic error in the program rather than just an exploit,  because that makes it seem like `$i` isn't meant to be ran at all

Comment: @ASliceOfBread Correct. An exploit just takes advantage of an unintended evaluation of the code. In this case, it's a bug that results in a parameter value being treated as a command instead of an argument to a parameter assignment. In others, it's something like `eval "$foo=3"`, where the programmer let the user specify the name of a variable to set, without checking first that the value of `foo` is *exactly* a valid identifier like `x`, and not an arbitrary expression like `rm -rf *; x`.

Comment: @ASliceOfBread The code can also be considered *underhanded*: it looks so innocent as to be overseen in a code review for security issues. For the C language this is a real problem and there's even a contest for it: http://www.underhanded-c.org/